# Determine the size of an image using ImgScalr

Tags: java, imgscalr

Hi I am currently using ImgScalr library and I have few markers to download images from an HTML document , however sometimes the images are of low quality,and if they are then I need to scan thru the html source to download all the images and use the one with the biggest size in bytes.

I use ImgScalr library, I need to know how I can check the size of the image in bytes to determine if it meets my quality requirements. Is it the right approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imgscalr author here - the library is focused on image operations only, operating on the uncompressed BufferedImage objects.

To know the actual file size you would just download all the images from the HTML page to a directory and then iterate through the files using the standard Java File operations to determine the file size.

If you are using Java 7+ you can use the handy [Files.size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size(java.nio.file.Path)) operation.

Comment: Thanks Riyad, is there a way to find out the size without creating a file from the Buffered Image object /Stream using Java JDK, I dont want to create a directory and physically store the files, if I can calculate the image size from the image stream then I can scan thru all the images and record the size of each one and then come back  and download again the one that happens to be the largest one in terms of the size .

Comment: It depends what you meant by 'size' -- I originally assumed you meant "file size" in which case you can use the suggestion above. If you mean "dimensions" (width x height) then there are faster ways to just read the metadata out of an image file (JPG) to determine the size -- here are a few libraries to help [link](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr/issues/25) -- I would say that just taking the biggest file-size is probably a roughly accurate way to determine the 'biggest' version of an image though.

Comment: Riyad, I actually mean size in bytes as well ,when I say biggest , however I dont want to create temorary files , as I am dealing with millions of images, and would rather prefer to determine the size in bytes of the image downloaded from a http link in memory to drive the further logic. Thanks.

Comment: @user1965449 Oh! I understand now... unfortunately you can't, the reason for that is 'BufferedImage' represents the raw, uncompressed pixel RBG(A) values. The only way to be able to tell how big the image is going to be once written to a file is to encode it with your encoder of choice (likely JPG) and give that encoder a chance to run and compress the image. So you'd have to go through that step, effectively writing out the file, to tell how big it's going to be. Otherwise if you have them in-memory as BufferedImages, just cheat and use 'biggest dimensions' I guess :)

Comment: much appreciated , I will go by the dimensions instead and I think it will work out better instead than the size in bytes approach .

Answer (score -1):

```
$dir = "/path/to/image/directory/*.jpg";   //Path to image folder and image type extension
$list = array();                           //Create and empty array

foreach(glob($dir) as $checkimages){
  $size = filesize($checkimages);
  if($size > 500000){                      //enter file size minimum
     $list[] = $checkimages;                //final array contains the images you seek
  }
}
```

This uses PHP to find all images in a folder, then checks each for a minimum files size, if meets criteria inserts into new array.

```
//Output to HTML each file in array
foreach($list as $output){
    echo $output.'<br/>';
}

// or 
print_r($list);
```

Comment: The question was about the Java library imgscalr